# Python error when running incremental duplicity backup to Backblaze B2

Tags: python, backup, deja-dup, duplicity

Running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on a VPS (Contabo), with Duplicity 0.8.21 and Python 3.10.12, and I am backing up to Backblaze B2. Full backups run fine, but I get Python errors when running an incremental backup with the same options and target folder.

Running a full backup of /root, /home, /opt, /etc, /tmp, and /var:

```
duplicity full --progress --exclude-filelist /home/duplicity_exclude / b2://[keyID]:[application key]@[B2 bucket name]
```

This works fine.

Now when running an incremental backup, I get errors:

```
root@vps:/# duplicity incremental --progress --exclude-filelist /home/duplicity_exclude / b2://[keyID]:[application key]@[B2 bucket name]
Reading globbing filelist /home/duplicity_exclude
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup date: Fri Sep  1 22:33:41 2023
GnuPG passphrase for decryption:
Retype passphrase for decryption to confirm:
Attempt of get Nr. 1 failed. TypeError: argument should be a str object or an os.PathLike object returning str, not <class 'bytes'>
Attempt of get Nr. 2 failed. TypeError: argument should be a str object or an os.PathLike object returning str, not <class 'bytes'>
Attempt of get Nr. 3 failed. TypeError: argument should be a str object or an os.PathLike object returning str, not <class 'bytes'>
Attempt of get Nr. 4 failed. TypeError: argument should be a str object or an os.PathLike object returning str, not <class 'bytes'>
Giving up after 5 attempts. TypeError: argument should be a str object or an os.PathLike object returning str, not <class 'bytes'>`
```

What in the world is going on?

Answer (score 0):

looks like the error discussed here https://gitlab.com/duplicity/duplicity/-/issues/701#note_1317189517

tl;dr - python b2sdk module changed the API and older duplicity throws the error above now. to solve it either

1. downgrade and pin the b2sdk module to version 1.19.0 or less
2. upgrade to latest duplicity version 2.1+